# nothing happen when i click the button java

Tags: java, swing

I have an app and when you run it you take a panel in order to add 3 values and after you need press the OK button in order to continue.

I put a Click() method but when i push OK nothing happen.

Also to mention when i am deluging is working but when i export it as executable jar is not.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel mlabel = new JLabel("Please provide xxxx",JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel uLabel = new JLabel("User ID:",JLabel.LEFT);
JPanel buttonField = new JPanel(new GridLayout (1,3));
JPanel userArea =  new JPanel(new GridLayout (0,3));


frame.setLayout(new GridLayout (0,1));
buttonField.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JButton confirm =new JButton("OK");
confirm.addMouseListener((MouseListener) new mouseClick());
buttonField.add(confirm);

App.insertText = new JTextField(20);
frame.add(mlabel);
userArea.add(uLabel);
userArea.add(insertText);
frame.add(buttonField);
frame.setSize(300,600);
App.credGet = false;
frame.setVisible(true);
```

and the Click :

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    App.un = App.insertText.getText();
    App.project = ((JTextComponent) App.insertProject).getText();
    //App.pw = char[] App.insertPass.getPassword();
    char[] input = App.insertPass.getPassword();
    App.pw = "";
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < input.length; i1++){
        App.pw = App.pw + input[i1];
    }
} 

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Comment: 1. Use the proper listener for the right need, and here never use a MouseListener in this way, and instead use an ActionListener when listening for JButton presses. 2. You have unusual field references suggesting possible over-use of static fields -- but I really can't tell based on what you've posted so far. 3. For better help, create and post a valid [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Line

```
confirm.addMouseListener((MouseListener) new mouseClick());
```

I suppose `mouseClick` is a class you posted in the example below. Why do you cast it to `MouseListener`? Does it not implement the `MouseListener`?

Anyway, you'll be better off replacing it with an `ActionListener` (anonymous class will work fine for you here), e.g.

```
confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...         
    }
});
```

Read [Pros and cons of using ActionListener vs. MouseListener for capturing clicks on a JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526555/pros-and-cons-of-using-actionlistener-vs-mouselistener-for-capturing-clicks-on) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("ButtonName");
//add button to frame
frame.add(button);    
//Add action listener to button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            System.out.println("You clicked the button");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) using something like this:

```
anyBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Your Code Here
    }
});
```

Or you could use a [Lambda](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/java-8-lambda-listener-example) as shown here:

```
anyBtn.addActionListener(e ->
{
    //Your Code Here
});
```

You should not be using a MouseListener in that way ever. That is not what it is intended for.

Comment: I used both ActionListener and Lambda but i am getting error.

Comment: @ChristosV Post your issues as a new question and link me to it.